# How do I get the line number of the source code from a byte offset in java?

Tags: java, bytecode, bytecode-manipulation, .class-file, bcel

I am manipulating a .class file. I am using the [InstrutionHandle](http://commons.apache.org/bcel/apidocs/org/apache/bcel/generic/InstructionHandle.html#getPosition%28%29) package to get the instructions one at a time. I have the byte offset of the instruction via [getPosition()](http://commons.apache.org/bcel/apidocs/org/apache/bcel/generic/InstructionHandle.html#getPosition%28%29) method
, can i get the source line number from the byte offset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends on whether the classfile is compiled with debugging information. Usually, the compiler will insert a `LineNumberTable` attribute which gives the original source line numbers corresponding to each range of bytecode. However, the `LineNumberTable` attribute is just metadata, so the author could put anything they want in there with minor constraints or just omit it entirely. (Typically done by compiling with `-g: none` or by running an obfuscator on it)

Anyway, the format of the attribute is number of entires (2 bytes) followed by (start pc, line number) pairs (both 2 bytes). You can also have multiple `LineNumberTable` attributes. Of course if you're using a library, it will probably decode these for you already.